# TypeError: google.visualization is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to work with Google charts API, but I get an error I can't understand:

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/statistics/overview.js"></script>
```

And the code from overview.js is like this:

```
var statisticsOverview = {
    init: function() {
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawIncomeChart());
        google.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawExpensesChart());
        google.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawEconomiesChart());
    },
    drawIncomeChart: function() {
        var data = [
            ['Year', 'Income'],
            ['October 2013', 1000],
            ['January 2014', 1170],
            ['March 2014', 660]
        ];
        var options = {
            title: 'Income Performance',
            colors: ['green']
        };
        var id = 'chart_income';

        this.drawLineChart(data, options, id);
    },
    drawExpensesChart: function() {
        var data = [
            ['Year', 'Expense'],
            ['October 2013', 1000],
            ['January 2014', 1170],
            ['March 2014', 660]
        ];
        var options = {
            title: 'Expense Performance',
            colors: ['red']
        };
        var id = 'chart_expenses';
        this.drawLineChart(data, options, id);
    },
    drawEconomiesChart: function() {
        var data = [
            ['Year', 'Savings'],
            ['2004', 1000],
            ['2005', 1170],
            ['2006', 660],
            ['2007', 1030]
        ];

        var options = {
            title: 'Savings Performance',
            colors: ['orange']
        };

        var id = 'chart_economies';
        this.drawLineChart(data, options, id);
    },
    drawLineChart: function(data, options, id) {
        console.log(google.visualization);
        var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(id));
        chart.draw(chartData, options);
    }
};

statisticsOverview.init();
```

This is strange, because console.log() will give me the google object with the property visualization. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is `init` part called?

Comment: Right after my object declaration(see last line of code)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't notice it.

Comment: Dynamic loading should help https://developers.google.com/loader/#dynamic-loading

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Timing problem. Typically you call google chart like

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
  ...
  }
```

So, when visualization package is loaded function to draw is called.

Now, in your case everything is done later, so you have to do:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});

function doStats() {

var statisticsOverview = {
    init: function() {
        console.log('init');
        this.drawIncomeChart();
        this.drawExpensesChart();
        this.drawEconomiesChart();
    },
    ...
};    

statisticsOverview.init()
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(doStats);
```

Similar result can be get using

```
setTimeout(function() {
    statisticsOverview.init();
}, 3000);
```

without wrapper function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, if I understand correctly, because the calls were asynchronous my object was initialized before the Google visualization?

Comment: Yes, it seems that package was not fully loaded when `arrayToDataTable` was called. At least for the first chart.

Comment: WTF, when the function says `onLoad`, it should trigger after everything is loaded o.O

Comment: It's a terrible library, I'm getting random failures because of this. If I drop some alert it works, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: I'd prefer calling `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(myfunc)` over the effort with a setTimeout call. Note that it's `google.charts.`, not only `google.`. And note that you can [stack multiple functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts), not only one. Useful when you have multiple graphs on one page..

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. This is working fine for me

```
    var timeout;
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    $(document).ready(function(){
       timeout = setInterval(function () {
          if (google.visualization != undefined) {
             drawChart();
             clearInterval(timeout);
          }
       }, 300);
    });

    function drawChart(range, type) {
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    .....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to call a function instead, I wanted to change the chart dynamically on input change. I have faced same issue and resolved it by using `.then(function(){});` as below:

Check this link: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#callback-via-promise

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]}).then(function(){
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
        ['Household', '10'],
        [' Savings, Investments & Debt', 20],
        ['Other',  30],
        ]);

        var options = {
        title: 'Expenditure Breakdown',
        pieHole: 0.5,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('income-expenditure-chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
});
```