# Google Charts and Angular 2 - a graph won't show

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-visualization

I'm learning Angular 2 and, as an exercise, I wanted to use Google Charts API.
Here's my component, in which I want to have a chart:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { WeatherAPIService } from './weatherAPI.service';

declare var google: any;


@Component({

  selector: 'my-graphs',

  template: `<h1>Charts for {{this.weatherAPIService.cityName}}</h1>
            <div id="chart_div"></div>            
            `,

  providers: [WeatherAPIService]
})

export class GraphsComponent implements OnInit {

    //googleLoaded;

    constructor(
                  private weatherAPIService: WeatherAPIService

            ) { }

    drawChart () {

      console.log(google.visualization);

      // Create the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
      data.addRows([
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
        ['Onions', 1],
        ['Olives', 1],
        ['Zucchini', 1],
        ['Pepperoni', 2]
      ]);


              // Set chart options
      var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                      'width':400,
                      'height':300};

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

    }

    loadGoogleChart() {
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawChart);

    }



    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadGoogleChart();
    }


}
```

If I understand it correctly, I should only call this.loadGoogleChart() function, because inside of that there is a callback to drawChart(), so I do not need to call drawChart() myself. Unfortunately I don't see anything when I run it - the component only has the `<h1>` header, which I set in the template, but chart_div is just empty.

What am I doing wrong?
I saw a similar question: [TypeError: google.visualization is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659671/typeerror-google-visualization-is-undefined)
but in that case the person who asked this got some results when console.log(google.visualization); was called. I don't see any message in my console.
So, I guess, drawChart() is never called. What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your line 
`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawChart);`
Can you change it to `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawChart());`

Also there was a prevailing error that would say you can't reinitialize the chart for subsequent calls. I think it was updated but i haven't checked. Anyway you can always have this function
 `checkloaded(): boolean {
    return !((typeof google === 'undefined') || (typeof google.visualization === 'undefined'));
  }`

Which you would call to see if it's loaded previously so that subsequent calls to initialize it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar enough with Angular 2's lifecycle, but having worked extensively with Google Charts in Angular 1.x, I don't think your code sample hear reflects the complexity of the pairing between the framework and the library.

One of the biggest issues you'll face is that you can only call load on google charts once. After it's already loaded, it will not trigger your callback if you call load again. That means handling loading on the component level is not generally suitable. If you change states and that component disappears, there's nothing handling the fact that the loaders service already exists.

Also, you can only have one callback, so it you have multiple components loading at the same time, one component will over-write the other's callback from google charts and you'll get a last-in-wins situation with callbacks.

I can't advice on Angular 2 specifics because I'm not up to date on the framework, but just keep in mind that the problem is too complex to be handled in a few lines of code. I do encourage you to try and work through it, though. One hacky approach I saw used before I found [Angular Google Chart](https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/), was to delay angular bootstrap until the google charts library loaded. That way you can be optimistic in all code and assume the google charts library is already loaded. No idea if that will work in Angular 2.