# loader.js:149 Uncaught TypeError: d is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

All of a sudden I get this on my console. I've been using google charts and I haven't change anything.

I am using chrome and it works fine on safari. I am trying to load

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: You realize that unless someone just experienced the EXACT same thing, then your question does not allow anyone to help you, right? Please edit your question to include: What environment are you working in, what js page failed, what it was supposed to do, was it one you wrote? What is var d? What does 'd' do and why is it being called? Etc.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue on all browsers.  Seems it's an issue on google's side.  Hopefully they fix it soon.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with loader.js. I just started receiving the same error on all of my pages using loader.js. Google server problem...

Sorry to post as an answer but I don't have the rep to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something happened with google's servers. I just experienced the same issue for the first time within the past 20 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659671/typeerror-google-visualization-is-undefined) by Anto Jurković. It seems to working so far.